# Problem to find ServiceUrl in a Core Console App to connect to a Bot with Bot Connector Assembly

Tags: c#, botframework

I have an bot web app running in azure with url : https://mybot.azurewebsites.net and message point https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

mybot is a placeholder for the name of the bot.

I want a console client to communicate with the bot deployed in azure and use the Bot Connector Assembly.

Now my Question is: I have a problem to find the right service url to connect to the bot. 
I tried:

- https://api.botframework.com
- Messagepoint : https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
- BotService : https://mybot.azurewebsites.net

I got always not found the resource as response.
Below the sample.

Could anyone help to get the right url?
Thx.

```
var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("myBotAppId", "myAppBotPwd");
        var serviceUri = new Uri("https://<mybot>.azurewebsites.net", UriKind.Absolute);
        var bot = new ChannelAccount() { Id = "mybot" };
        var user = new ChannelAccount() { Id = "me" };

        var activity = new Activity()
        {
            Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
            Recipient = user,
            From = bot,
            Text = "Hello Bot"
        };

        var param = new ConversationParameters()
        {
            Members = new ChannelAccount[] { user },
            Bot = bot
        };

        using (var client = new ConnectorClient(serviceUri, credentials))
        {
            var conversation = await client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(param);
            var response = await client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversation.Id, activity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect your azure bot with local streaming? I mean want to send request azure portal to your bot and get response right?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do? The URL 'https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages' works only for 'POST' request and not 'GET' request as you are posting a message to the bot. The serviceURL property needs to be set to the endpoint of your message sink/client. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for more clarity.